# Java System.err.printの制御

Tags: java

進捗状況を数値でアウトプットしつつ作業を行いたく以下のように書きました。

```
for (int iRun = 0; iRun <nRun; iRun++){
   double[] d = new double[10000];
   Arrays.fill(d, 1);
   if (100 < nRun && iRun % (nRun / 100) == 0)
      System.err.print("\rWorking " + Math.ceil(100.0 * iRun / nRun) + "%");
}
System.err.println("\rWorking " + Math.ceil(100.0 * iRun / nRun) + "%");
System.err.println("fin");
```

,
こちらが想定しているコンソール上での最終状態です。（数値は変化しつつ100で止まる）

```
Working 100.0%
fin
```

, しかしおおくの場合（5回に3、4回は）期待通りいかず、以下のようになります。

```
Working 100.0%Working 100.0%
fin
```

.
for終了後に `Thread::sleep`等を用いても改善は見られません。

```
double[] d = new double[10000];
Arrays.fill(d, 1);
```

部は 本来の作業の部分を置き換えていますが、上記でも問題は発生しています。

`nRun=10000`において発生しております。`nRun`が小さいときは発生しない模様です。（私の環境下では）

恐らくコンパイラによる所だと思いますが、どうやって常に期待どおりの結果にすることができるでしょうか？
実行環境は
OS:CentOS 7.3
Java: 1.8.0_121
IntelliJ IDEA the Java IDE 2017.1 上での実行
となっております。

＃
皆様の回答から、IDE上での実行が原因である可能性が濃厚で、実際に他のターミナルからの実行では発生しませんでした。詳しい方には呆れられても仕方のない顛末ですが、気がつかせていただきありがとうございました。

Comment: Ubuntu Linux 17.04 と Java 9-ea, コンソールは vt100(`TERM=vt100`) で試してみたのですが、同様の現象は発生しませんでした。そちらで使用している OS や Java のバージョン、ターミナルプログラムと端末の設定を追記すると良いかと思います。それから、書き間違いかと思いますが、for loop 内で `int iRun = 0` としているので、for loop 外の `System.err.println("\rWorking " + Math.ceil(100.0 * iRun / nRun) + "%");` の `iRun` が未定義になってしまいます。

Comment: Mac(OS X El Caption 10.11.6), java version "1.8.0_112" でも20回程度試行しましたが再現しませんでした。

Comment: metropolis様, maot様 確認ありがとうございます。 iRunについては間違いです。本来100としていたのですが、ひょっとすると```println```の中身が 定数なのでループの内外で最適化がかかっているのかもと思い、nRun/nRunとしていました。

Comment: [「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を参考に問題が再現するコードを質問に記載すると、回答が得られやすいです。例えば、`doSomething();`は無くても問題が再現しますか？ 再現するならこの部分はいらないです。これが無ければ再現しないのなら、`doSomething();` の内容も記載する必要があります。

Comment: mjy様 御指摘ありがとうございます。 発生例を示しました。もうしわけないです。

Comment: dockerでCentOS 7.3.1611, java 1.8.0_12の環境を用意し、`nRun=10000`で50回試行しましたが再現できません。再現可能なコードを記載することはできますでしょうか？他の方のコメントにもありますが、記載されているコードはそのままではコンパイルできません。また「結構な頻度」というのは具体的に何回試行して何回発生する頻度でしょうか？例えば100回に1回を「結構な頻度」とされている場合は、私が試行した50回程度では再現しないこともあります。

Comment: こちらでも再現しませんね…とりあえず、ループ終了直後に `System.err.print("\r\u001B[2K");` を入れてみてはどうでしょう。`\u001B[2K` はエスケープシーケンスで clear current line(現在行の表示内容を消去) です。

Comment: maot様 きちんと計算してはいませんが少なくとも5割は超えています。 metropolis様 ありがとうございます。 そして皆様、つたない質問にこたえていただきありがとうございました。あまりにも皆様の環境下で再現例がでないということでもう一度皆様の回答を見て原因がおそらくしぼれました。お恥ずかしいのですが、最初のmetropolis様のターミナルプログラムに対する質問を飛ばしてしまっていましたが、環境はIntellij IDEAで実行していました。本当に初歩的なミスにお時間さいていただき大変恐縮です。ありがとうございました。不勉強でした。 一応その状況での再現も記しておきます。 本当にありがとうございました。